# When i tried to uninstall ubuntu i accidentally uninstalled the incorrect version

Tags: uninstall

So I tried to uninstall ubuntu but I clicked the wrong one to uninstall and I can no longer access anything to uninstall the other version of ubuntu. I used the website, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller and followed the number 2 option. When i try to access my computer i can either go to the bios menu or i am faced with a black screen that says trying to recover grub. I was wondering if anyone had faced this problem before and knew what i should do. I should also mention that I'm trying to install windows 8.

Comment: You can install Windows 8 straight away. You don't need to "uninstall" Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to install windows8 before installing Ubuntu just to avoid boot problems.

boot to ubuntu using Live-usb then, install os-uninstaller and uninstall the OS you want to remove. after that go ahead like this.

open the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

then copy past this commands to it one after another,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and by this you will install a tool called boot-repair.

open boot repair from dash and you'll get this window

[image]

choose the recommended repair and follow the steps.

**Note** you have to be connected to they Internet when using boot-repair.

**Note2** if you still want to install windows8 after Ubuntu, and grub goes missing do the steps above to fix it.